# Why am I getting this weird issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, blueprint

I'm using Blueprint a React-based UI toolkit for the web. I'm using their table code and it's typescript but I'm getting an weird error.

My code is just like - https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/blob/develop/packages/docs-app/src/examples/table-examples/tableEditableExample.tsx but with a really small changes that make typescript work on my computer.

The error I have is with this line of code
`<Example options={false} showOptionsBelowExample={true} {...this.props}>`

Error text

> JSX element type 'Example' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
>   Type 'Example' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': context, setState, forceUpdate, props, and 2 more.
>
> JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property.

Comment: Could you please share your code? It might help us debug the issue =)

Comment: @JordyvD Yes, I uploaded the code on pastebin. Check the link to view it https://pastebin.com/RFet9Zat